# Fancybox Modal control location

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox afterShow to display image descriptions on the side via overlay like so:

```
afterShow : function (){
    var description = "<div class='hidden_tab'>"+$("#tab").html()+"</div>"
    $('#fancybox-overlay').html(description);
}
```

The problem is that I need modal to be false so users can click out. But the hidden_tab tabs, when clicked, also exit fancybox.

Is there a way to section where modal takes affect? Or a workaround? I have tried setting `z-index` for the hidden_tab to be high but this did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set `modal : false` then try adding `closeClick : false` (which prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox)

BTW, the default value of `modal` is `false`. Don't assume that people will necessarily understand why `modal` was set to `true` in your script.